# Zee's derivation of Cartan-Weyl basis

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am having trouble in understanding [Zee]'s derivation (in Chapter VI.3) of the following property of the Cartan-Weyl basis of a complex Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$:

$$
[H^i, E_\beta] = \beta^i E_\beta
\tag{16}
$$

where $\{H^i\}$ is a basis in the Cartan sub-algebra $\mathfrak{h}$, and $E_\beta$ is the "ladder operator" of the root vector $\beta$.

First, Zee assumes for simplicity that $\mathfrak{g}$ is the complexified Lie algebra of a compact (matrix) Lie group $G$, so that all finite-dimensional representations of $G$ is (up to a similarity transformation) unitary ([Pal] Theorem 16.6). Then for the corresponding representation of the algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, one can choose basis vectors $\{X^a\}$ of $\mathfrak{g}$ which are all rerepsented by Hermitian matrices (in Zee's book everything is multiplied by $i$ comparing to mathematicians' notation).

In particular, the above argument applies to the adjoint representation $\pi^{ad}$ of $\mathfrak{g}$, which is $n$-dimensional ($n \equiv \dim \mathfrak{g}$). The structure constants under the basis $\{X_a\}$ are defined by

$$
[X^a, X^b] = i {f^{ab}}_c X^c
$$

and are matrix elements of the adjoint representation: the basis vector $X^a$ of $\mathfrak{g}$ is represented by

$$
{[\pi^{ad}(X^a)]^b}_c = i {f^{ab}}_c
\tag{4}
$$

which can be made Hermitian. In Zee's notation the matrix is $T^a \equiv \pi^{ad}(X^a)$. Suppose that the basis $\{X^a\}$ is chosen such that $X^1, ..., X^r$ ($r$ is the rank of $\mathfrak{g}$) spans the Cartan sub-algebra; then we change their notation to $H^1, ..., H^r$.

Since $[H^i, H^j] = 0$ for all $i,j = 1,...,l$, the set of matrices $\{T^i\}_{i=1}^r$ (which are all Hermitian) can be simultaneously diagonalized by a unitary matrix $U$:

$$
{(\tilde{T}^i)^a}_b \equiv U^\dagger {(T^i)^a}_b U
= -\beta^i(a) \delta^a_b
\tag{11}
$$

where $-\beta^i(a) \in \mathbb{R}$ is the $a$th eigenvalue of the Hermitian matrix $T^i$. Then we redefine the adjoint representation matrices for all $\{X^a\}$ to

$$
{[\tilde{\pi}^{ad}(X^a)]^b}_c
\equiv {(\tilde{T}^a)^b}_c
= U^\dagger {(T^i)^a}_b U
$$

Then on page 368, Zee claims that one can make the structure constants satisfy

$$
i {f^{ia}}_b = \beta^i(a) \delta^a_b
\quad (i = 1,...,r)
\tag{?}
$$

which then leads to

$$
[H^i, X^a] = [X^i, X^a]
= i {f^{ia}}_b X^b
= \beta^i(a) \delta^a_b X^b
= \beta^i(a) X^a
$$

(no summation over $a$ on the RHS).

Here comes my question: I believe that once $\{X^a\}$ are chosen, the structure constants are fixed, and are independent of the representation of $\mathfrak{g}$. In particular, they should be independent of a similarity transformation of the representation matrix. I may even be unfortunate to start with a basis in the vector space carrying the adjoint representation such that the adjoint representation is not unitary (a similarity transformation is needed). So I am confused on why a diagonalization of the adjoint representation allows Zee to change the structure constants as in eq.(?). What is Zee actually doing here?

---

[Zee]: Anthony Zee, *Group Theory in A Nutshell for Physicists* (2016)

[Pal]: Palash B. Pal, *A Physicist’s Introduction to Algebraic Structures:
Vector Spaces, Groups, Topological Spaces and More* (2019)